# Android: App with services keeps showing up in Overview Screen after calling finish() and System.exit(0)

Tags: android, android-service

The App has several running services in the background. They run before and I want them to continue running even after the App closes.

After I call from `Activity`:

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

The App removes from foreground, but in the Overview Screen (long menu btn press) the App still appears. And it's always with same behaviour:

- First click on the App to open: The Overview Screen closes and nothing happens.
- Second click on the App to open: The Overview Screen closes and the App come back to the last point it works OK before calling `finish()` etc.

Why is it happens and how can I properly close the App (keeping the background services still running)?

EDIT: It seems something more general: [Android: Behaviour of App in Overview Screen after calling finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624598/android-behaviour-of-app-in-overview-screen-after-calling-finish)

Comment: You should use `Service` instead of 'IntentService' and you need to return `Service.START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` of the service. That will keep your service running even if the app is killed. And on low-memory if android kills the service, it will be created and started again.

Comment: @RaviSisodia Thanks, what about the app not closing even after finish? Is this because the service?

Comment: What do you mean by 'app is not closing' ? The 'Overview screen' is the list of recent apps the user have visited. If your app is in the list it doesn't always mean that it is running.

Comment: That strange behaviour... first click on the app from the overview nothing happens and opening again the overview and clicking the app - the app resumes

Comment: That might be because of `System.exit(0);`. Try removing it.

Comment: Did it... same strange behaviour....

Comment: @RaviSisodia I noticed it is something general so I opened new Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624598/android-behaviour-of-app-in-overview-screen-after-calling-finish