# Android: Behaviour of App in Overview Screen after calling finish()

Tags: android

I noticed some strange behaviour of Apps after calling finish():

I created empty new App containing single simplest `Activity` with single button performing single row of code `finish();`. The App have no `Handler`, `AsyncTask`, `Service` etc. just simple one `Activity`.

1. After calling `finish();` the App disappears from the foreground.
2. Opening the Overview Screen - The app displayed. It's normal because the Overview display recent Apps.
3. Clicking on the App from the Overview screen does nothing.
4. Opening again the Overview Screen the App still displayed.
5. Clicking again the App from Overview Screen now open the App.

Why in second time I click the App from the Overview Screen the App opens?

This is related to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606559/android-app-with-services-keeps-showing-up-in-overview-screen-after-calling-fin?noredirect=1#comment53067115_32606559), firstly I thought it's maybe because of complex app contacting services etc. but then I tested it on mentioned above simple demo App.

Thanks,